# Javascript Loan Calculator with While loop

Tags: javascript, css, math, for-loop, while-loop

The program is supposed to determine how many months it will take to pay off the loan. Cannot seem to figure out how to fix my mathematical calculations. Not sure if it's the while loop that's wrong. Instead of determining the monthly payment based on user input, the input shows the total number of months (which i do not want. the program is supposed to do that). It is supposed to look like this: http://snag.gy/9vzGi.jpg Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

 function fixVal(value,numberOfCharacters,numberOfDecimals,padCharacter) { 
    var i, stringObject, stringLength, numberToPad;            

    value = value * Math.pow(10,numberOfDecimals);                 
    value = Math.round(value);                                   
    stringObject = new String(value);                            
    stringLength = stringObject.length;                          
    while(stringLength < numberOfDecimals) {                     
        stringObject = "0"+stringObject;                    
        stringLength=stringLength+1;                      
    }

    if(numberOfDecimals>0) {                       
        stringObject=stringObject.substring(0,stringLength-numberOfDecimals)+"."+
        stringObject.substring(stringLength-numberOfDecimals,stringLength);
    }

    if (stringObject.length<numberOfCharacters && numberOfCharacters>0) {
        numberToPad=numberOfCharacters-stringObject.length;      
        for (i=0; i<numberToPad; i=i+1) {
            stringObject=padCharacter+stringObject;
        }
    }

    return stringObject;                                      
}

function buildTable() {

    var amount=parseFloat(document.getElementById("loanAmt").value );
    var numpay=parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPay").value );
    var rate=parseFloat(document.getElementById("intRte").value );

    rate = rate / 100;
    var monthly = rate / 12;
    var payment = ((amount * monthly) / (1-Math.pow((1 + monthly), - numpay)));
    var total = payment * numpay;
    var interest = total - amount;

    var msg = "<table border='4' width='75%'>";
    msg += "<tr>";
    msg += "<td>Month</td>";
    msg += "<td>Principal Paid</td>";
    msg += "<td>Interest Paid</td>";
    msg += "<td>Loan Balance</td>";
    msg += "</tr>";

    newPrincipal=amount;
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= numpay) {
        newInterest=monthly*newPrincipal;
        reduction=payment-newInterest;
        newPrincipal=newPrincipal-reduction;

        msg += "<tr><td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>"+i+"</td> \
                <td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>"+fixVal(reduction,0,2,' ')+"</td> \
                <td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>"+fixVal(newInterest,0,2,' ')+"</td> \
                <td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>"+fixVal(newPrincipal,0,2,' ')+"</td></tr>";

        i++;
    }


    msg += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = msg;


}


</script>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    background: black;
    font-family: arial;
}

#contentwrap {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
    background: #FFFFCC;
    text-align: center;
    border: 6px red solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
}

table {
    border: 5px blue double;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-shadow: yellow 3px 3px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    color: red;
}

#button {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 150px;
}

.contentTitles {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.style {
    background: lightblue;
    font-family: comic sans ms;
    border: 6px blue double;
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="contentwrap">

<div id="header">Javascript Loan Calculator</div>

<form>

<div class="contentTitles">Enter Loan Amount<br />
<input type="text" id="loanAmt" class="style"><p />

Interest Rate (%)<br />
<input type="text" id="intRte" class="style"><p /> 

Monthly Payment Amount<br />
<input type="text" id="monthlyPay" class="style"><p />

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
<input type="button" value="Process Data" id="button" onClick="buildTable()">
</div>

</form>

<center>
<div id="results" style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
</center>


</div> <!-- ends div#contentwrap -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the input to be the monthly payment, please don't call the respective variable `numpay`.

In your case, it seems more practical not to calculate the number of months beforehand. You can use the while loop to build the table and calculate the duration of the loan at the same time:

```
function buildTable() {

    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loanAmt").value );
    var monthly = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPay").value );
    var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("intRte").value );

    rate = rate / 100 / 12;

    var m = 0;    // number of months

    while (amount > 0) {
        var interest = amount * rate;
        var principal = monthly - interest;

        if (principal > amount) {
            principal = amount;
            amount = 0.0;
        } else {
            amount -= principal;
        }

        // build table: m + 1, principal, interest, amount

        m++;
    }

    // display table
}
```

Comment: Works perfect and the variables make more sense. Thank you.

Comment: Any idea why a "0" wont output before the decimal point when the number is less than 1.00?  Ex- it shows ".99" instead of "0.99"

Comment: You need to zero-pad your number to one more than the number of decimals after the point before inserting the decimal point, so that, say, 72 will become 072 for `fixVal(0.72, 0, 2, ' ')`. Change `while(stringLength < numberOfDecimals)` to `while(stringLength < numberOfDecimals + 1)` in the first `while` loop of `fixVal`.